# Error in classic asp String type mismatch

Tags: asp-classic

I keep getting this error

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: '[string: ""]'

```
intHPrimary  = rtrim(request.form("chkHPrimary"))
if  len(intHPrimary) > 0 and isNumeric(intHPrimary) then 
    intHPrimary = cint(intHPrimary)
else 
    intHPrimary = 0
end if 
<%if intHPrimary > 0 then%>---This is where I get my error
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkHPrimary" value= "1" checked />
<%else%>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkHPrimary" value= "1" />
<%end if%></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of refactoring should help;

```vb
<%
Dim checked
Dim intHPrimary : intHPrimary = RTrim(Request.Form("chkHPrimary") & "")
If Len(intHPrimary) > 0 And IsNumeric(intHPrimary) Then intHPrimary = CInt(intHPrimary) Else intHPrimary = 0
If intHPrimary > 0 Then checked = " checked" Else checked = ""
%>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkHPrimary" value= "1"<%= checked %> /></td>
```

Try not to duplicate HTML when it is unnecessary and instead workout your logic and apply the result afterwards. Also, make sure that the code is inside ASP preprocessor tags `<% %>` or it will not be treated as code.

Comment: `Else checked = ""` does not obligatory :)

Comment: @Zam I like to be descriptive and that way there’s no ambiguity.